# Inverse of a matrix with multiple answers

Tags: linear-algebra

I am asked to find the inverse of the matrix

```
     [ 1  0  2]
A =  [-3  1  4]
     [ 2 -3  4]
```

Which I can find by finding to echelon form of [A I]

On my calculator I get (both by A^-1 and rref([ A I ]))

```
        [16  -6   -2]
1/30 *  [20   0  -10]
        [07   3   01]
```

However the book lists the inverse as

```
       [8    03   01 ]
A^-1 = [10   04   01 ]
       [3.5  1.5  0.5]
```

While some numbers make sense (row 3 / 2, row 1 is almost row1/2 but seems a sign is missing, row3 not sure though) I can't see how they got their answer. Is it a mistake? Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inverse is correct, as you have written $\mathbf{A}$, you get:

$$\mathbf{A}^{-1}=\frac{1}{30}\begin{pmatrix}16 & -6 & -2 \\ 20 & 0 & -10 \\ 7 & 3 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

And we can check this by making sure the product $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{-1}=\mathbf{I}_{3\times3}$:

$$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{-1}=\frac{1}{30}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 \\ -3 & 1 & 4 \\ 2 & -3 & 4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}16 & -6 & -2 \\ 20 & 0 & -10 \\ 7 & 3 & 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore you have got the correct inverse and there is a mistake in the book.

Moreover, you can easily show that their matrix (let's call it $\mathbf{B}$) is wrong, by showing $\mathbf{AB}\neq\mathbf{I}_{3\times3}$:

$$\mathbf{AB}=\begin{pmatrix}1 &0 & 2 \\ -3 & 1 & 4 \\ 2 & -3 & 4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}8 & 3 & 1 \\ 10 & 4 & 1 \\ 3.5 & 1.5 & 0.5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}15 & 6 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

So it looks like they didn't finish their Row Reduction and wrote the penultimate stage as the answer instead.

Comment: Thank you I assume that but was rather worried I went astray somewhere and didn't realize it.

Comment: @Zimm3r No problem, if you look at the amendment to the bottom of my answer you can see where they likely made their error.